# Angular ng-repeat search for two fields of an object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-filters

Say i have the following `array`

```
$scope.myArr = [{
    name: 'Marc Rasmussen',
    phone: 239470192,
    title: 'It Dude',
    description: 'Hello my name is Marc i am testing the fact that i can search for two fields in an object'
}, {
    name: 'Louise',
    phone: 1234567890,
    title: 'HR Director',
    description: 'I am also testing'
}, {
    name: 'Leonardo',
    phone: 123499,
    title: 'Actor',
    description: 'I have never won an oscar'
}];
```

Now as you can see i have the following fields:

- name
- phone
- title
- description

Now i repeat these using `ng-repeat`

```
<div ng-repeat="obj in myArr">
    <div>
        name: {{obj.name}}
    </div> 
    <div>
        phone: {{obj.phone}}
    </div>
    <div>
        title: {{obj.title}}
    </div>
    <div>
       description: {{obj.description}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Now what i want is that i want a single textfield to search for results in  both the `name` and `description` and no other field

Normally you would care a variable such as `$scope.search.$` but this would search in all fields. alternativly you could make an input field for each field however this does not forfill what i wish to accomplish.

So my question is how can you make 1 input search for two fields at the same time?

here is a fiddle of the above code:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dzwg9zL0/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this article might help you out:
[Filtering by Multiple Specific Model Properties in AngularJS (in OR relationship)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13216115/filtering-by-multiple-specific-model-properties-in-angularjs-in-or-relationship)

Essentially taking advantage of angular's filter and using a predicate function on each item in the repeated array.