# How to use or condition for ng-options filter in angular select

Tags: angularjs

This is my js data

```
$scope.dynamicCmb = [{
        id: 1,
        label: 'aLabel',
        subItem: ['aSubItem1','aSubItem2','aSubItem3']
    }
            , {
                id: 2,
                label: 'bLabel',
                subItem: [ 'bSubItem' ]
            }
    ];

    $scope.selectedid = 2;
```

Below is the html

```
 <select ng-options="item.subItem for item in dynamicCmb | filter:{id:selectedid}" ng-model="selected"></select>
```

above code is working fine. If I update selectedid value then it will filter based on id field. But I want to use or condition i.e, I want to search based on id or label. So if I pass id for selectedid then it should filter on id , if I give label for selectedid then it should filter on label. I want to do something like below

```
<select ng-options="item.subItem for item in dynamicCmb | filter:{id:selectedid | name:selectedid}" ng-model="selected"></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do this in following way by making custom function in js code by this  methodology

[Filtering by Multiple Specific Model Properties in AngularJS (in OR relationship)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13216115/filtering-by-multiple-specific-model-properties-in-angularjs-in-or-relationship)