# search.$ also searches for ids

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Il jump right to the case.

Basicly when you have an array of objects like this:

```
{id: 1, name: "Hello", location: "New york", streetNumber: 50}
```

Then you have an input field:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="search.$" />
```

And the following table:

```
<table>
    <thead>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Location</th>
    <th>Street number</th>
    </thead>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in items | filter:search">
        <td>
            {{item.name}}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{item.location}}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{item.streetNumber}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

So when you type into the search field:   "1".

Then you will also get the object where the `id` matches 1.

My question is how can i exclude items that are not shown?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/11424/)

Comment: It's worth looking at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13216282/4045532)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, take a look at the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)

> A special property name ($ by default) can be used (e.g. as in {$:
>   "text"}) to accept a match against any property of the object or its
>   nested object properties.

That's why the results with ids satisfying the criterion get included.

#### Solution 1, simple but slower working

Add another filtering

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in items | filter : search | filter : { id: '!search.$' }">
```

#### Solution 2, difficult but quick

Consider writing your own filter, e.g.

JS

```
app.filter('searchFields', function () {
    return function (array, fields, string) {
        fields = fields.split(',');

        var i,
            fieldsLength = fields.length;

        return array.filter(function (item) {
            for (i = 0; i < fieldsLength; i++) {
                if (typeof item[fields[i]] === 'undefined') {
                    continue;
                }

                return (item[fields[i]] + '').indexOf(string) !== -1;
            }
        });
    };
});
```

HTML

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in items | searchFields : 'name,location,streetNumber' : search.$">
```