# AngularJS filter of more than one property

Tags: angularjs, filter

I use this filter in my AngularJS application and now I need also to filter or firstname. Currently my filter looks like this:

```
| filter: {user: {surname: searchEmployeesText}}
```

Is there a possibility to filter also of firstname without a filter function?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filtering by Multiple Specific Model Properties in AngularJS (in OR relationship)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13216115/filtering-by-multiple-specific-model-properties-in-angularjs-in-or-relationship)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your custom filter gives you more flexibility,

**HTML**

```
<li ng-repeat="user in users | filter:isExists(searchText)">First :  {{user.name}} || Last : {{user.lname}}</li>
```

**JS** here i am searching entered searchText in fname as well as in lname.

```
$scope.isExists = function (searchText) {
        return function (user) {
            return (!searchText || (user.lname.indexOf(searchText) > -1) || (user.name.indexOf(searchText) > -1));
        }
    };
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pupydqwt/1/)**