# Using aliases with multiple filters

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter, angularjs-limitto

I have this code:

```
<tr ng-repeat="person in ctrl.persons
            | filter : { name: filterName, email: filterEmail} as filtered">

Number of persons filtered by mail and name: {{filtered.length}}
```

Now I add another filter:

```
<tr ng-repeat="person in ctrl.persons
                    | filter : { name: filterName, email: filterEmail} 
                    | limitTo : ctrl.size as filtered">

Number of persons filtered by mail and name: {{filtered.length}}
```

My problem is that the number of persons filtered by mail and name is wrong now, because it's limited to `size`. What's the best workaround to solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: You should use a function in order to filter your repeat. In this function, add your different filters, and apply your limitTo on it.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/13216282/4781975

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using brackets:

```
<tr ng-repeat="person in filteredPersons = (ctrl.persons
                        | filter : { name: filterName, email: filterEmail})
                        | limitTo : ctrl.size as filtered">

Number of persons filtered by mail and name: {{filteredPersons.length}}
```