# uib pagination search/filter on multiple columns

Tags: angularjs, html, pagination

I have multiple columns in a table such as router id, status, name, location. I want to search the table based on status and column. For now, I can search on status. But if I try to add name in addition to status for searching, it is not working. I am sure I am wrong in syntax. Can somenone help me out?
Here's my code

```
 <tr ng-repeat="router in routerList | orderBy: rule|filter : {'status' : naviagtion.searchText }| limitTo:5:5*(naviagtion.currentPage-1) ">
  </tr>
```

I want to add name for the filter as well.

Comment: Please check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13216115/filtering-by-multiple-specific-model-properties-in-angularjs-in-or-relationship and see if it will work for you.

Comment: thanks. It was helpful :)