# How to filter data in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, input-filtering

I'm trying to implement a simple search textfield. 
I want it to display contacts by filtering their name and phone number. It seems like whenever I type in a letter , it shows me all of the contacts' names that have that letter in their name, but it also searches the other attributes of each contact (address, city, mail, etc), so if a contact's name does not contain the letter, it's still shown becuase its other attributes contain it.
Obviously that is not what I am trying to implement.

I want it to be able to filter contacts by both name and phone number.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="query" placeholder="search"/>
<div ng-repeat="c in contacts|filter: query"> ...<\div>
```

How can I solve this problem? 
Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple to filter based on one field: just change your filter to `| filter:{name: query}`

It's simple to filter based on two fields if they **both** have to match: just change your filter to `| filter:{name: query, phoneNumber: query}`.

It's harder to filter based on two fields if you want **either** to match. [Here's someone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13216115/filtering-by-multiple-specific-model-properties-in-angularjs-in-or-relationship) who had the same question. The first response has a simple hack to make things work if you're just playing around, but if you have more data you'll want to work through [this blog post](https://toddmotto.com/use-controller-filters-to-prevent-digest-performance-issues/).

By the way, your question was likely downvoted because this isn't too hard to Google. Searching [angularjs filter by field] got me partway there, and then [ng-repeat filter multiple fields] took me to the results I've linked above.